# remove system notification programmatically

Tags: android

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` in my android code which detects incoming messages. I want to remove default notification of incoming message (generated by Android device) when message has my keyword. How can I do that?

Comment: You cannot do that because those are not system generated notifications but they are generated by default messaging application in your device

Answer (score 0):

remove this particular code or comment it from your program:

```
  NotificationManager mNotifyManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
```

Comment: what does this mean?